# Instance method 'items(cellIdentifier:cellType:)' requires that 'Model' conform to 'Sequence'

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm writing a code that shows the values I've received from the server in the table view. However, the following error occurs: Instance method 'items(cellIdentifier:cellType:)' requires that 'Model' conform to 'Sequence'
This is my code. I don't know why errors occur.

```
        rank.bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "rankingCell", cellType: RankingCell.self)) { rkc, model, cell in
            cell.nickNameLbl.text = model.nickName
            cell.profileImage.image = model.profileImage
            cell.Ranking.text = model.profileImage
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This is my viewController
An error occurs in the rx part.

```
struct RankingModel: Codable {
    var ranking: Int = -1
    var nickName: String = ""
    var profileImage: String = ""
    
    enum RankingModelKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case ranking
        case nickName
        case profileImage
    }
}
```

And this is my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table view displays an array (Sequence) of values. The compiler is telling you that your model is not an array.